# What does ?? do in rust?

Tags: rust, operator-keyword

Here is an example of it in [action](https://github.com/stjepang/smol/blob/master/examples/websocket-server.rs#L31):

```
let msg = stream.next().await.context("expected a message")??;
```

Is it just `?` being done twice? If so why does it need to be done in this case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it's just `?` being done twice; there is no `??` operator.

`stream` is a `WsStream`. `WsStream` is a type defined in the same module. `WsStream` implements `Stream`.

`stream.next()` invokes [`StreamExt::next`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.5/futures/stream/trait.StreamExt.html#method.next), which returns a future that yields `Option<Self::Item>`. `Self::Item` is defined to be `tungstenite::Result<Message>` (`= Result<Message, tungstenite::Error>`) for `WsStream`. This means that the result of `stream.next().await` is of type `Option<Result<Message, tungstenite::Error>>`.

Then, [`context`](https://docs.rs/anyhow/1.0.31/anyhow/trait.Context.html#tymethod.context) is applied on the value. `Context` is implemented for `Option<T>` and for `Result<T, E>`, but the output is always a `Result`. However, `context` doesn't flatten anything, so we end up with `Result<Result<Message, tungstenite::Error>, anyhow::Error>`. The two uses of `?` therefore serve to handle the two levels of `Result`s.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's just the `?` operator done twice. A quick example:

```
fn result_of_result() -> Result<Result<i32, String>, String> {
    Ok(Ok(42))
}

fn f() -> Result<(), String> {
    println!("{:?}", result_of_result());
    println!("{:?}", result_of_result()?);
    println!("{:?}", result_of_result()??);
    Ok(())
}

fn main() {f();}
```

Outputs:

```
Ok(Ok(42))
Ok(42)
42
```

Answer (score 0):

It's approximately an [operator for `unwrap()` or `try!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/edition-guide/rust-2018/error-handling-and-panics/the-question-mark-operator-for-easier-error-handling.html), so this could be expanded to something like:

```
let msg = try!(stream.next().await.context("expected a message")).unwrap();
```

With async code you're going to see `await?` quite often, but `await??` does seem odd.